# Storing files with extension in database as BLOB

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, blob, files

Recently during development process I've faced **file storage** issue. I'm not sure which solution is the best one that's why I decided to write this question. I don't have a lot experience of database administration that's why any tip can be really useful for me.

In my application project I have several types of **files** that have relationship with specific **tables**, for example:

- **Invoice** has one **scan**
- **User** has one **document**
- **Transaction** has one **receipt**
- **Building** has many **photos**

... etc.

All those files: `scan | document | receipt | photo` have different extensions(pdf/jpg/png etc.).

I decided that files corresponding for each table will be stored as `BLOB` datatype. Because of `BLOB` usage there is need to store **file extension** somewhere in database.

I was considering few possible solutions:
(For demonstration purposes I will attach simple tables visualization)

[image]

user | invoice | building_photo | transaction have require file stored as `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB`, but extension of files is missing. What would be the best way of storing that? as `VARCHAR` column in each table or as separate table?

Example of extension storage in each table:

[image]

This solution is the easiest one to implement, extension as additional `VARCHAR` is handy when I'm inserting new data, but I'm repeating this information since I will have two files with the same extension.

Example of extension storage in separate table:

[image]

This solution seems to be more optimized but little bit harder to manage while inserting new data. I would be grateful for any suggestion about problem described above.

Another implementation that I've considered is to not store all files in separate tables but instead create one table called `file` that will contains file `BLOB` and then invoice | user | transaction | building etc.
will have relationship to that table. Visualization below:

[image]

In this case again I'm keeping **extension** in separate table, but **file data as well**. All files are in the same place but I'll end up with large table and a lot **one to one** relationships. If such solution makes sense also I would be grateful for option, or maybe there is another way of doing such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "user has one document" (and the others) is really a business rule - something you might need to change in the future, not a data rule. Therefore it should be enforced by triggers / constraints, not your schema

I'd go with a schema like this:

```
USERS -< USER_DOCUMENTS >- FILES

INVOICES -< INVOICE_SCANS >- FILES

BUILDINGS -< BUILDING_PHOTOS >- FILES

TRANSACTIONS -< TRANSACTION_RECEIPTS >- FILES
```

Where FILES looks like this:

```
FILES
file_id
content_type
name
data (BLOB)
```

While we're at it "transactions" is a very overused term in databases.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just want to clarify. USER_DOCUMENTS is an associative entity? (contains user_id and file_id?) and FILES.content_type is VARCHAR that stores file extension?

Comment: @Marcin yes, that's what I'd do. Or content_type could point to a content_types table